# Is it possible to replace apache solr in broadleafcommerce with ElasticSearch?

Tags: spring-mvc, elasticsearch, broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to use [broadleafcommerce](http://www.broadleafcommerce.org) and customize it.On study i found it uses **Apache Solr** . However, i am already handy with 
**ElasticSearch** as i am currently using ElasticSearch only in my workplace. so, i'm curious as if i can replace that customizable code of broadleafcommerce with ElasticSearch. If it is possible, i also want to know how long will it take or what will be its difficulty level ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The product is open source, you can have a look at the code yourself. [Here is the package](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/tree/master/core/broadleaf-framework/src/main/java/org/broadleafcommerce/core/search/) that would need to be made solr independent. As far as I see there are quite some dependencies on Solr now, but maybe you can give it a shot and contribute it back. In the end that's the power of open source.

I can't tell exactly how much work that would be since I don't know the product and what it does with the data. The solr schema would need to be translated to the related elasticsearch mapping, then the indexer will need to be converted in order to push data to elasticsearch (otherwise if technically doable you could write a river that imports data in elasticsearch from the framework itself). Last step is to convert the search code together with the facets, highlighting etc.

Maybe you (or the people behind the project) might want to have a look at [spring data](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data) which has now a community driven spring-data-solr project and an [unofficial elasticsearch implementation](https://github.com/BioMedCentralLtd/spring-data-elasticsearch) too.